# Validating start and end date in codeigniter start date less than end date

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, validation, date

these are used in view page please add the javascript to validate this date i am using code igniter

HTML Code:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">Mfg. date </label>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="startDate" name="mfg_date" value="">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">Exp. Date </label>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="endDate" name="exp_date" value="">
</div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_medicines"/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" />Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
  $("#ed_endtimedate").change(function() {
    var startDate = document.getElementById("ed_starttimedate").value;
    var endDate = document.getElementById("ed_endtimedate").value;

    if ((Date.parse(endDate) <= Date.parse(startDate))) {
      alert("End date should be greater than Start date");
      document.getElementById("ed_endtimedate").value = "";
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your submit button.

```
function validateForm() {

    var startDate = document.getElementById("startDate").value;
    var endDate = document.getElementById("endDate").value;
    var x = new Date(startDate);
    var y = new Date(endDate);

    if (x > y) {
        alert("Start date must be less than end date!");
        document.getElementById("endDate").value="";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: mgf date is less than exp date

Comment: endDate should be greater than mgf date?

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_medicines"/>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onClick="validateForm" >Add</button>

Comment: <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">       
function validateForm() ...............................{
        alert("Start date must be less than end date!");
        return false;
    }
}
     </script>
</head>

Comment: <a href="javascript:void()" onclick="validateForm()">Validate Form</a>

Comment: but ok button click the data inser to data base

Comment: Please use the javascript function on blur of end date field not on button `      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="endDate" name="exp_date" value="" onblur="validateForm()">`

Comment: the date change and corret then the submit button work why i do

Comment: now the msg only show and i click ok button in alert box then click the submit button the the falls insert

Comment: @mywork I told you please use that function on blur of you end date field and remove from submit button, thats it

Comment: :- ya thats work, but the alert box show  and i click the ok button ,then i click the submit button the data isert   ( i'm not change the date)

Comment: I edited the answer and now it makes clear the end date field when the start date greater than end date and please try it nwo

Comment: ok that work one more... the star date and end date are not same,but here that are same and not msg pop up

Comment: if ((x > y) ||(x != y))    i use this so that working  thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "voted the alert box to model box"?

Comment: modal box how implement

Comment: Please don't parse strings with the built-in parser. Not all browsers support input type date, and the result of `var x = new Date(startDate)` could be anything.  The value must be validated and must be parsed with either a bespoke function or a library (there are plenty of good ones to choose from). If *a* and *b* are Date objects, then `!=` will **always** be true as it compares them as objects. `<` and `>` work because they convert Dates to their time value and compares them as numbers.